# Rails 4 stylesheet_link_tag sometimes uses relative paths?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this weird problem, where *sometimes*, `stylesheet_link_tag` links to the relative path to the wrong path? The exact same code works whenever I try to debug and find out what's happening.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap/sales_workflow/classic", :media => "all" %>
```

Both these work as they should - Most of the time. But sometimes, they link to 
    `/en/listEM3181/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` and `/en/listEM3181/assets/bootstrap/sales_workflow/classic.css`  I don't know what page - But `/en/list/EM3181/` is an existing page - And I suspect that.

Also I can't see why `/list/EM3181` becomes `/listEM3181`, suddenly.

Is there anything that can be done? Is it a known problem?

Comment: what is your `action_controller.asset_host` set it in application.rb and/or config/environments/*.rb?

Comment: It isn't set - What makes me wonder is, that it only happens sometimes, and not all the time?